# Visual Studio 2017 - How to configure command terminal inside IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, terminal, console

Does VS Studio Professional 2017 (not Visual Studio Code) has integrated console/terminal to run commands directly from IDE from the same folder?

To give example - InteliJ has really nicely integrated console/terminal inside IDE by default:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-system-console.html

Comment: There is the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017.

Comment: Command Window? That is not the same as CMD for example. Can not run dos commands..

Comment: It's like win cmd but works better with .net commands.

Comment: And is installed with VS. Can be found in Start-->scroll down to VS folder or search by name.

Answer (score 1):

You can install some extensions for use terminal in VS.

In visual studio, Tools->Extensions and Updates menu and search for terminal in online.
I tried ***Whack Whack Terminal*** before. When you install it, you can open terminal window under Windows->Other Windows section. 
You can download here and this one opens the integrated window.

> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielGriffen.WhackWhackTerminal

Answer (score 1):

You can make a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" window (a CMD instance) that is set to some version of "the current folder" by doing:

1. Open Tools -> External Tools
2. Click Add
3. Set the following settings:

> **Title**: Command Prompt &Here
>
> **Command**: %systemroot%\system32\cmd.exe
>
> **Arguments**: /K ""c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat" -no_logo"
>
> **Initial directory**: $(ItemDir)

4. Leave "Close on Exit" checked and click OK

*Note the weird double-quotes-ed-ness of the "arguments" parameter (two at the beginning, and two more here and there) - it's important to get them right*

At that point, you now have a "**Command Prompt Here**" entry in the **Tools** menu that will open to the folder associated with the file that has focus in VS.  It's adaptable to other versions of VS by playing games with the path to the BAT file.

Comment: Thanks. Will this open CMD as a separate window or will it be integrated inside VS (e.g. as additional panel without switching from CMD back to VS)?

Comment: A brand-new, 1985-looking CMD window.  You'll need to [alt]+[tab] back and forth.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping for more integrated solution.. This sounds more as another shortcut to CMD (which I can run by myself without VS) minus path to a folder..

Comment: The path to the folder thing makes it very handy.  You open one, run a few commands and close it.  Then open another one a few minutes later.  And, it's a "VS Command Prompt".  The paths to all the SDK and VS commands (ILDASM, XSD.exe, etc.) are all set up.